# Reset MacBook Air without admin account or command s

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I got a whole bunch of MacBooks from my old high school which I've repaired. The only issue is a few of them are still password locked, I tried the <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> trick as you do but when I would hold it, it would just load into the user login screen. is there anyway to bypass this or a different method of wiping the macs?

Edit: Ive also tried to swap out the nvme, I'm certain that the new one works but when I plug in the boot drive it asks for a password again.

Answer (score 1):

If the Mac asks for a password before boot (just a password field, no user name) what you are encountering is the firmware password, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455

The procedure to removing the firmware password depends on the MacBook model, for all Intel MacBook Air models without a T2 chip (pre-2018) only Apple can remove the firmware password. You will need to visit an Apple Authorised Service Center and bring proof that you own the device(s).